# setImageDrawable don't scale correctly with no resource images

Tags: android

I'm trying to load a image stored in filesystem into a imageButton. But it not scaling correctly. The file is the same (t700.png) in drawable resources and in filesystem, but the result is diferent.

This work fine:

```
button.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.t700));
```

This change scale / size and get bigger image:

```
String filePath = VideoActivity.this.getFilesDir()+File.separator+EPGApiService.LOGOS_DIR+File.separator+channel.getLogoFile();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
BitmapDrawable imgDrawable = new BitmapDrawable( this.getResources(),bitmap);
button.setImageDrawable(imgDrawable);
```

I need same result..

NOTE:
if I do

```
BitmapDrawable logoBitmapDrawableFromDisk = new BitmapDrawable(VideoActivity.this.getResources(),logoBitmap);
BitmapDrawable logoBitmapDrawableFromDisk2 = new BitmapDrawable(logoBitmap);
BitmapDrawable logoBitmapDrawableFromRes = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.t700);
```

The Drawables Bitmaps sizes are not the same!

logoBitmapDrawableFromDisk size is 410x123

logoBitmapDrawableFromDisk2 size is 205x62

logoBitmapDrawableFromRes  size is 820x246

The real file is the same. I need the same size on this two ways.

Comment: What version of android are you using? `R.drawable.t700` is a file or is an alias to another Drawable resource?

Comment: It's refers to t700.png image file in res/drawable

Comment: in docs: BitmapDrawable(Resources res) 
 This constructor was deprecated in API level 18. Use BitmapDrawable(android.content.res.Resources, android.graphics.Bitmap) instead to specify a bitmap to draw with.

Comment: As i can understand from android documentation, if the icon is under res/drawable folder, `BitmapDrawable(bitmap)` and `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.t700);` should be the same.

Comment: The icon is not in res/drawable folder becouse are donwloading in runtime. That is the problem...i want to control scaling...

Answer (score 0):

`BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap)`

> Create drawable from a bitmap, setting initial target density based on the display metrics of the resources.

It looks bigger because it is using the resource object to adjust the image to your screen's density.

To avoid that use `BitmapDrawable(bitmap)`

Or resize your png to look right in a mdpi device.
Then `BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap)` will give you the correct look in all devices.

The correct way to have same look in all devices is create different icons for each device density.
Start with the dimension for mdpi density. The dimensions for each the other densities should be calculated based in the following values:

hdpi multiply by 1.5
xhdpi multiply by 2
xxhdpi multiply by 3

Each icon should be put under separate folders with the appropriate name depending on density:

mdpi -> res/drawable_mdpi
hdpi -> res/drawable_hdpi
xhdpi -> res/drawable_xhdpi
xxhdpi -> res/drawable_xxhdpi

Set the ImageButton source in xml or use `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.t700);` the device will automatically select the right one.

For more information see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Don't work with BitmapDrawable(bitmap). The logos are look more small and differect size. I need to adjust images to fixed bottons. But only work using button.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.t700));

Comment: Only work setting density manually:  logoBitmap.setDensity(200);

Comment: Which is the real width and height of t700.png?

Comment: Real size are 410x123. Yes, I agree with you, but problem are icons are downloading using external JSON Service. Well, getting URL by JSON and then Logo File from this URL. I can't modify WebService but it's not mine.